# Regex: find substrings with a pattern with some conditions

Tags: python, regex

I try to prepare a pattern to find all the substrings from the text with this format

```
system:microsoft,
flow:to_server,
vho:file-was-closed,
heur250:unknown.file
```

Also, I want to exclude substrings where parts before or after `:` include only digits

```
03:00
file:123
```

I don't want to catch substrings where the part before `:` is equal to `mailto`

```
mailto:user
```

And I don't want to catch substrings where parts before or after `:` end with some extensions like `jpg`, `png`

```
cid:image003.png
```

I've written the pattern but it doesn't work properly.

```
pattern = r'(?!^\d+$)(?!mailto)[\w\d\.-]+:[\w\d\.-(?!(jpg|png))]+'
```

Could you help me to change that and explain what I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try:

```
(?<!\S)(?!mailto|(?:\S*:)?(?:\d+|\S*\.(?:jp|pn)g)([\s:]|$))[\w.-]+:[\w.-]+(?!\S)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/IrO3nO/1). Admittedly, the last part of the pattern can be more specific to avoid things like `...:...` to be valid, but that's up to you I guess.

---

- `(?<!\S)` - Assert position is not preceded by a non-whitespace;
- `(?!mailto|(?:\S*:)?(?:\d+|\S*\.(?:jp|pn)g)([\s:]|$))` - A negative lookahead with alternation: Avoid 'mailto:', avoid trailing '.jpg' or '.png' or just digits on either side of the colon;
- `[\w.-]+:[\w.-]+` - The pattern to match at least 1+ characters from the given class on either side of the colon;
- `(?!\S)` - Assert position is not followed by a non-whitespace char.

Comment: Thank you! But `findall` still returns me smth like `'ailto:kolesnikov.vn'`, `gmt-05:00`. And one important thing - I try to extract all of this substrings from the huge piece of a text

Comment: @JvdV I doubt whitespace boundaries will work because of `system:microsoft,` (see comma at the end), but I also added this solution to my answer. The only solution I see is the one relying on the best regex trick ever as 1) we cannot rely on word boundaries as the match contains non-word chars, 2) the matches seem to be followed with chars other than whitespace chars. Also, using `.*?` in the lookahead in this situation is fragile since it can overmatch.

Comment: I think you are right about those points. I changed to `\S*` previously, but I think the 2nd pattern in your answer does the trick best if considering all punctuation problems OP may face when searching in larger text. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2):

**If your matches are inside whitespace boundaries**, you can use

```
(?<!\S)(?!mailto:|\d+:)[\w.-]+(?<!\.jpg|\.png):(?!\d+(?!\S))[\w.-]+(?!\S)(?<!\.jpg|\.png)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZcgbUb/3).

*Details*:

- `(?<!\S)` -  left-hand whitespace boundary
- `(?!mailto:|\d+:)` - immediately to the right, there can be no `mailto:` or one or more digits followed with a `:` char
- `[\w.-]+` - one or more word, `.` or `-` chars
- `(?<!\.jpg|\.png)` - no `.jpg` or `.png` immediately to the left are allowed
- `:` - a colon
- `(?!\d+(?!\S))` - only digits until the whitespace or end of string are allowed
- `[\w.-]+` - one or more word, `.` or `-` chars
- `(?!\S)`  - right-hand whitespace boundary
- `(?<!\.jpg|\.png)` - no `.jpg` or `.png` immediately to the left are allowed.

**If your matches are located in any context** you can use a solution like

```py
import re
text = "system:microsoft flow:to_server vho:file-was-closed heur250:unknown.file,  file.png:word, 03:00,  file:123, mailto:user, cid:image003.png"
pattern = r'\bmailto:[\w.-]+|\b\d+:[\w.-]+|[\w.-]+:\d+|[\w.-]+:[\w.-]*\.(?:jpg|png)(?![\w.-])|[\w.-]*\.(?:jpg|png):[\w.-]+|([\w.-]+:[\w.-]+)'
print( [x for x in re.findall(pattern, text) if x!=''] )
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/uDPcbA).

Output:

```
['system:microsoft', 'flow:to_server', 'vho:file-was-closed', 'heur250:unknown.file']
```

Note that this solution is based on the ["best regex trick ever"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick). *Details*:

- `\bmailto:[\w.-]+|` - whole word `mailto:` and then one or more word, `.` or `-` chars, or
- `\b\d+:[\w.-]+|` - word boundary, one or more digits, `:`, and then one or more word, `.` or `-` chars, or
- `[\w.-]+:\d+|` -  one or more word, `.` or `-` chars, `:`, one or more digits
- `[\w.-]+:[\w.-]*\.(?:jpg|png)(?![\w.-])|` - one or more word, `.` or `-` chars, `:`, zero or more word, `.` or `-` chars, then `.` and `jpg` or `png` not followed with a  word, `.` or `-` char, or
- `[\w.-]*\.(?:jpg|png):[\w.-]+|` - zero or more word, `.` or `-` chars, `.`, `jpg` or `png`, `:`, and then one or more word, `.` or `-` chars, or
- `([\w.-]+:[\w.-]+)` - Group 1 (we'll output this value only): one or more word, `.` or `-` chars, `:`, and one or more word, `.` and `-` chars.

All the parts before the last Group 1 pattern are there to filter out unwelcome matches.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I try to find it in a text so I removed `^` and `$`, but I still have substr like `ailto:user` after that

Comment: @ldevyataykina The second solution looks the most comprehensive to me.